# how to match an array of array with the same values in mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I have the following call to match so as to return an object:

```
    String[][] parameters = new String[][] {
            new String[]{
                    eq("provider"),
                    eq("myProvider")
            }
    };

    when(supportApiNotificationsProvider.getByServiceName(
            "supportApiNotifications",
            parameters))
            .thenReturn(<an-object>);
```

but this way the mock always returns `null`. On the other hand, if I change the parameter offered to the mock as the following:

```
    String[][] parameters = new String[][] {
            new String[]{
                    anyString(),
                    anyString()
            }
    };
```

it works! I'm sure about the tho string values passed, hence I guess it's something about the `eq` matchers I defined.

Comment: What does the method declaration of `getByServiceName` look like? `public <an-object> getByServiceName(String serviceName, String[] parameters){}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `eq` is misplaced, I would rather define `parameters` like this:

```
    String[][] parameters = eq(new String[][] {
            new String[]{
                    "provider",
                    "myProvider"
            }
    });
```